# Debug Assertion Failed error when accessing function in DLL

Tags: c++, dll

I'm currently learning how to create a C++ library to be referenced in other projects, and I am running into an issue with a "Debug Assertion Failed" error: `is_block_type_valid(header-> _block_use)`. I followed the walkthrough shown here: [Create and use your own Dynamic Link Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp). Oddly, I am getting the expected answer if I just ignore the error.

My DLL currently only has one function:

cpp:

```
int calculate_crc(std::string msg)
{
    std::vector<std::string> msg_vector = [](std::string& msg1) {
        std::string next;
        std::vector<std::string> result;

        // for each char in string
        for (std::string::const_iterator it = msg1.begin(); it != msg1.end(); it++)
        {
            // if we hit a terminal char
            if (*it == ' ')
            {
                if (!next.empty())
                {
                    // add them to the result vector
                    result.push_back(next);
                    next.clear();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                next += *it;
            }
        }
        if (!next.empty())
        {
            result.push_back(next);
        }

        return result;
    } (msg);

    int crcReg = 0xFFFF;

    // iterate through each element in msgVector
    for (auto&& element : msg_vector)
    {
        // step 2: xor operation performed on byte of msg and CRC register
        crcReg ^= [](std::string hex) {
            std::map<char, int> map;

            map['0'] = 0;
            map['1'] = 1;
            map['2'] = 2;
            map['3'] = 3;
            map['4'] = 4;
            map['5'] = 5;
            map['6'] = 6;
            map['7'] = 7;
            map['8'] = 8;
            map['9'] = 9;
            map['a'] = 10;
            map['b'] = 11;
            map['c'] = 12;
            map['d'] = 13;
            map['e'] = 14;
            map['f'] = 15;

            return map[hex[1]] + (map[hex[0]] * 16);
        } (element);

        // step 3-5 are repeated until 8 bit shifts
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            int crcCopy = crcReg;
            crcReg >>= 1;

            if ((crcCopy & 1) == 0)
                continue;
            else
                crcReg ^= 0xA001;
        }
    }

    return crcReg;
}
```

h:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef OMRONLIBRARY_EXPORTS
#define OMRONLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define OMRONLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <iostream>

extern "C" OMRONLIBRARY_API int calculate_crc(const std::string msg);
```

Comment: FYI, there is a much easier way to fill your `std::vector` by using `std::istringstream` and `operator>>` to read whitespace-separated words from `msg`: `std::vector<std::string> result; std::istringstream iss(msg); std::string word; while (iss >> word) { result.push_back(word); }` And you don't really need the `std::map` in the CRC loop, you can convert chars `'0'..'9'` to integers by simply subtracting `'0'` from them, and `'a'..'f'` chars by subtracting `'a'`. Or, don't even parse hex string manually at all, use `std::stoi()` with `base=16` instead, or equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` is not a safe type to use in a DLL function parameter.  Non-POD types should *never* be passed over a DLL boundary, unless they are type-erased (such as by using a `void*` pointer) and are only ever accessed *directly* by code on *one* side of the boundary and not the other side.

Assuming the caller is even using C++ at all (C-style DLLs can be used in non-C/C++ languages), it may be using a different `std::string` implementation.  Or it may be using a different C++ compiler, or a different version of the same C++ compiler, or even just different settings for alignment, optimizations, etc.  And even if all of that matches the DLL, it will likely be using a different *instance* of the memory manager that the DLL uses for its `std::string` implementation.

If you want to pass a string to a DLL function *safely*, use a C-style `char*` string instead.  You can use `std::string` inside the DLL, if you want to, eg:

```cpp
int calculate_crc(const char* msg)
{
    use msg as-is ...

    or

    std::string s_msg = msg;
    use s_msg as needed ...
}
```

```cpp
extern "C" OMRONLIBRARY_API int calculate_crc(const char* msg);
```

Comment: I see. So what you're saying is when you create a DLL, you want to avoid using includes as much as possible and just stick using native C++ functions/classes. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: It is not just a matter of includes. Any class (outside of abstract interfaces) is general not safe to pass over the DLL boundary, as there may be differences in alignment, padding, vtable logic, etc. You just can't assume that the DLL and caller are using the same implementations.  So only pass around data that is interop-safe, like raw types that C uses. That also goes for calling conventions on functions, too. Stick to only `__cdecl` and `__stdcall`, as just about all C/C++ compilers (and most C-compatible languages) support them.

Comment: @AndrewNguyen the answer doesn't mention includes at all.  Read it to mean *any* C++ class.

Comment: That was it though. I changed the parameter from std::string to char* and that solved my issue with the errors. Thank you again for the help, couldn't have done it without you guys!